# How to setup nginx when using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below is my ngionx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        location /beta/ {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:9001;
        }

        location /qa/ {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:9002;
        }

        location /alpha/ {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:9003;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://www.google.com;
        }
    }
}
```

and below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  Reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    restart: always
  GQLbeta:
    image: gql-beta
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    restart: always
  GQLqa:
    image: gql-qa
    ports:
      - 9002:80
    restart: always
  GQLalpha:
    image: gql-alpha
    ports:
      - 9003:80
    restart: always
```

When I run docker-compose up -d, all container is running good.

Then I went localhost:80 on my browerser, it show 
[image: pic]

which I expected to see google page.

And when i went to localhost/beta, it will show

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

which i expected will go to localhost: 9001

Why this happened? Am i miss something to setup?

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` in the docker container is the container itself, so you should to give a names to your app containers and describe them as a upstreams - it will fix your `502`. With default location, try this:

```
location / {
    return 301 http://google.com;
}
```